# Set sap.ui.commons.DatePicker by default to current date

Tags: javascript, datepicker, sapui5

I was wondering if there's a simple possibility to set the default date of a [DatePicker](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/DatePicker.html) control?
I'd like on date picker to hold the current date and another one to hold (current date - 1 month).

Here's my way using the onAfterRendering method:

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd  = date.getDate().toString();

    var ending = yyyy + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]); // padding     
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("ending").setYyyymmdd(ending);

    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
    yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
    mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    dd  = date.getDate().toString();
    var beginning = yyyy + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]); // padding
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("beginning").setYyyymmdd(beginning);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply set the Date() value to the DatePicker's `value` property? That way there's no need to decompose the Date() value to fit the `yyyymmdd` property ;-)

See this example http://jsbin.com/mujuvu/1/edit

Comment: I was trying it that way, but somehow couldn't get it to work. Maybe just too tired ;-) Thanks anyway!